# How do we do regexp with negation with coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, regex-negation

I'm using Coldfusion.
The following syntax seems to remove all HTML tags for the `str` variable:

```
ReReplaceNoCase(#str#,"<[^>]*(?:>|$)","","ALL")>
```

However, I'd like to keep both `<div>` and `</div>` intact. How can I do that?

Comment: possible dublicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970817/how-can-i-clean-html-tags-out-of-a-coldfusion-string

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a regex, I would recommend using [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/). It makes parsing and manipulating html fragments much easier.

Download and install JSoup. Create a [Whitelist](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html) with the tags you wish to keep. Then scrub your html string with [JSoup.clean(...)](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer):

```
jsoup = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup");
whiteList = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist");
cleanString = jsoup.clean( yourHTMLString, Whitelist.none().addTags( [ "div" ] ));
writeDump( cleanString );
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.